# Cookies to store quiz answers information in Django

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to make a quiz app with Django as backend.

The way I want to do it is by showing a multiple choice question to the user, where he/she will select whatever answer he/she wants. After that, the user will click on "Next question", and that question will disappear and the next one will show up.

I was thinking about storing what questions and answers the user has already answered in a session cookie and once he/she answers the ten questions that would make up the quiz, the webpage shows the total score.

How could I store session info of that kind? Is there an easy way to do the "Next question" button and show the next question in the same page?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Didn't you already ask the same question here?

Comment: You're asking multiple questions here. Have you read the django docs about this topic?
[How to use sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/sessions/)